# Differences applied to a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

How can i apply the Differences command to a list of matrices?
I don't want to use a do cycle.

```
Do[ΔM[k] = M[[k]] - M[[k - 1]], {k, 1, Length[M]}]
```

I tried with Map, MapThread etc etc, but i don't get the result!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Differences`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) should work directly on your list of matrices, assuming that each matrix has the same dimensions.  Compare its output with the more verbose [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) equivalent:

```
SeedRandom[0];
M = RandomInteger[9, {5, 3, 3}];

Table[M[[k]] - M[[k - 1]], {k, 2, Length[M]}]

Differences[M]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 2, -7}, {-2, 5, -4}, {-6, 8, 0}},
>  {{-2, 3, 7}, {4, -1, 8}, {-2, -2, -6}},
>  {{-5, 4, -5}, {1, 1, -2}, {6, 3, 6}},
>  {{9, -5, -2}, {4, 1,  2}, {1, -2, -6}}}
>
> {{{0, 2, -7}, {-2, 5, -4}, {-6, 8, 0}},
>  {{-2, 3, 7}, {4, -1, 8}, {-2, -2, -6}},
>  {{-5, 4, -5}, {1, 1, -2}, {6, 3, 6}},
>  {{9, -5, -2}, {4, 1, 2}, {1, -2, -6}}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, sometime I feel really stupid :)

Comment: @Kowalski You're welcome, and you shouldn't; operating over arrays is rather unusual from what I've seen and unless you've been using *Mathematica* (or APL or something) for years I think these "mistakes" are common.  A related point: a number of functions operate on heads other than `List` even if they do not advertise that they do, e.g. `Sort[foo[3, 1, 2]]`.  (Though that is in the `Sort` documentation.)  Therefore it is often worth *trying* a function directly on a non-`List` expression to see what happens.